# Problem with showModalDialog when postback!

Tags: showmodaldialog

Dear all! I use showModalDialog to display form get data. When click button to postback server, IE auto open new window. Anh when choose data, it has close, but popup don't close and return value. Please held me. Thanks all!
Best regard.

Answer (score 2):

@sibe,

Please add <base target="_self" /> tag in 'head' part of your dialog page.

Regards

Lalit Dwivedi

Answer (score 0):

Some times target=self is not handled properly because of response.write statements in the code file,try removing them and try again